# Default sort of target table after insert when using Merge statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Following along with this example using the Merge statement
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Im trying to understand why in the final results (after the merge), StudentID 4 shows up in the results BEFORE StudentID 3.  Yes, I know I can order the results, but Im curious what defaults are at work here. See code below, along with before/after results.  Can someone explain this?

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
CREATE TABLE StudentDetails
(
StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
StudentName VARCHAR(15)
)
GO
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(1,'SMITH')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(2,'ALLEN')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(3,'JONES')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(4,'MARTIN')
INSERT INTO StudentDetails
VALUES(5,'JAMES')
GO 

--SELECT * FROM dbo.StudentDetails

CREATE TABLE StudentTotalMarks
(
StudentID INTEGER REFERENCES StudentDetails,
StudentMarks INTEGER
)
GO
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(1,230)
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(2,255)
INSERT INTO StudentTotalMarks
VALUES(3,200)
GO 


-- see results before Merge
SELECT * FROM dbo.StudentTotalMarks
    StudentID   StudentMarks
    1           230
    2           255
    3           200
```

So now we do a merge

```
MERGE StudentTotalMarks AS stm
USING (SELECT StudentID,StudentName FROM StudentDetails) AS sd
ON stm.StudentID = sd.StudentID
WHEN MATCHED AND stm.StudentMarks > 250 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET stm.StudentMarks = stm.StudentMarks + 25
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(StudentID,StudentMarks)
VALUES(sd.StudentID,25);
GO 



-- see results after MERGE
SELECT * FROM dbo.StudentTotalMarks
StudentID   StudentMarks
1             255
4             25
3             225
5             25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **absolutely no implicit sort order !!**

It does not matter in which order you insert your data. It might come back like this or not. So - to the point - sorting is **random**.

An alternative was the usage of `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col)` (or other functions with `... OVER(ORDER BY...)`), which will return a sorted resultset (if it is sorted after a unique key and you do not use multiple functions with sorting effect).

Find details [here: General Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

But: The only way to **ensure** some sort order is an `ORDER BY` onto the outer-most `SELECT`.

Comment: It's worth noting that without `ORDER BY` there is no _stability_ to the returned results, i.e. the next update to SQL Server may change the query optimizer in a way that alters the order of the results.

Comment: @HABO, Yes I would not rely on `OVER(ORDER BY ...)`... But don't you read this *There is no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using ROW_NUMBER() will be ordered exactly the same with each execution unless the following conditions are true (numbered list)* as guarante to *return sorted exactly the same with each execution*, as long as the conditions are fullfilled?

Comment: I agree with both your answer and comment. The point I was trying to make is that some users may have code that "works" without `ORDER BY` due to a happy accident: the results always come back in the same order. At least until they update SQL Server, add an index, or tickle some other thing that causes a generation of a new execution plan or underlying optimization. We both agree that if order is important to the application then it must be stated explicitly.